# How to enable dotenv variables for a file inside the /public folder in a Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have very little experience with configuring Webpack, and I'am a bit overwhelmed by this issue.

I've been working on a Vue2 project built on top of this [boilerplate](https://github.com/petervmeijgaard/vue-2-boilerplate). The project has a folder called `public` which contains the entry point file `index.html`. Inside that `index.html` file I can normally access .env environment variables (e.g. `process.env.VUE_APP_PAGE_TITLE`).

I've included an HTML fragment inside the `public` folder, `navbar.html`, because I want it to be available for other applications via https://example.com/public/navbar.html. However, I cannot seem to get my environment variables working inside `./public/navbar.html` even though they work just fine in `./public/index.html`. I assume this is a problem with my webpack config.

I know I can edit my Webpack config by editing a file in my project root called vue.config.js. This file contains a configureWebpack object, but I have no idea how to make it enable environment variables inside `./public/navbar.html`. Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:
Here's my vue.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

function resolveClientEnv() {
  const env = {};
  Object.keys(process.env).forEach((key) => {
    env[key] = process.env[key];
  });
  env.BASE_URL = '/';
  return env;
}


module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {        
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        // This is the generated file from the build, which ends up in public/navbar.html
        filename: 'navbar.html',
        // This is the source file you edit.
        template: 'public/navbar.html',
        templateParameters: (compilation, assets, pluginOptions) => {
          let stats;
          return Object.assign({
            // make stats lazy as it is expensive
            get webpack() {
              return stats || (stats = compilation.getStats().toJson());
            },
            compilation,
            webpackConfig: compilation.options,
            htmlWebpackPlugin: {
              files: assets,
              options: pluginOptions,
            },
          }, resolveClientEnv());
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

This is what my custom HTMLWebpackPlugin adds to the configuration according to `vue inspect`:

```
{
  options: {
    template: 'public/navbar.html',
    templateContent: false,
    templateParameters: function () { /* omitted long function */ },
    filename: 'navbar.html',
    hash: false,
    inject: true,
    compile: true,
    favicon: false,
    minify: 'auto',
    cache: true,
    showErrors: true,
    chunks: 'all',
    excludeChunks: [],
    chunksSortMode: 'auto',
    meta: {},
    base: false,
    title: 'Webpack App',
    xhtml: false
  },
  childCompilerHash: undefined,
  childCompilationOutputName: undefined,
  assetJson: undefined,
  hash: undefined,
  version: 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this standard plugin to generate `navbar.html`. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin.

If you read the docs, the `templateParameters` option is what you pass env variables to. Those variables will be available in `navbar.html`.

This is the same plugin that vue-cli uses for `index.html`. If you run the vue [`inspect`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-inspect) command, you can see what options they provide to the plugin. You'll need to read the source code for `resolveClientEnv()` to see how it works.

Example:

```js
    /* config.plugin('html-portal') */
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
      {
        templateParameters: (compilation, assets, pluginOptions) => {
                // enhance html-webpack-plugin's built in template params
                let stats
                return Object.assign({
                  // make stats lazy as it is expensive
                  get webpack () {
                    return stats || (stats = compilation.getStats().toJson())
                  },
                  compilation: compilation,
                  webpackConfig: compilation.options,
                  htmlWebpackPlugin: {
                    files: assets,
                    options: pluginOptions
                  }
                }, resolveClientEnv(options, true /* raw */))
              },
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true
        },
        chunks: [
          'chunk-vendors',
          'chunk-common',
          'portal'
        ],
        template: 'C:\\Users\\Eric\\workspace\\arc-core\\portal\\client\\templates\\portal.html',
        filename: 'portal.html',
        title: 'Arc Portal'
      }
    ),
```

That's a bit much, a minimal example would be:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    // This is the generated file from the build, which ends up in public/navbar.html
    filename: 'navbar.html',
    // This is the source file you edit.
    template: 'templates/navbar.html',
    templateParameters: {
        MY_VAR: 'myVar'
    }
}),
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, but I cannot get my env variables working inside navbar.html. Would you happen to have any idea why? I added my updated vue.config.js to my original question. Also, I ran vue inspect and the output seems to suggest my attempt at configuring HtmlWebpackPlugin doesn't change the original HtmlWebpackPlugin or add a new one, but does add an anonymous object that contains the template info I've typed into vue.config.js.

Comment: Try hardcoding an env variable, see if that works. If it does, we'll know the plugin is working, but something is wrong with `process.env`

Comment: Hardcoded variable didn't work, so I'm guessing there's something wrong with the plugin config. Unfortunately I have no idea what it might be. :/

Comment: i'm having trouble getting this working myself. I don't understand what one is supposed to do to get environment variables from `process.env` into the `public/index.html` file.